# Css content using TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm struggling to transform the following code snippet to use Tailwind css but without success so far.

Original code:

```
<li>
   <Link to="/test">abc</Link>
</li>
```

css:

```css
ol li:not(:last-child)::after {
  color: red;
  margin: 0 10px;
  content: '/';
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the css file and put all those rules in tailwind? The part with that content, `/`, seems impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class `after:content-['/']`

```html
<li>
  <a 
    class="after:content-['/'] after:inline"
    href="/test">abc
  </a>
</li>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/ztw0UhpFpg

Source: https://dev.to/j471n/how-to-use-before-and-after-in-tailwind-css-1he

Comment: the problem with your answer is that it adds the '/' character after each <li>, it shouldn't put it after the last <li>

Comment: I was focusing on the `/` since `The part with that content, /, seems impossible.`